# Logic app - reading xml message from web service and storing in a database

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a logic app that reads xml messages from a queue accessed via https, and stores the values in an sql database.

I have walked through the logic apps tutorials on msdn and read much of the documentation, but it has not prepared me for the challenge. The tutorials and step by step guides are extremely simple.

I would appreciate some guidance on where to start with this.

Comment: How would you like the Logic Apps to be triggered, on new message, timer? What's the queue? Is it Azure queue or something else?

Comment: For clarity, the Logic App would just be an http client.  Any queue is hidden by the http endpoint?

Comment: Storing to Azure SQL or bringing it in your local machine ? or somewhere else